# Wordpress post thumbnail size

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this line: `<?php the_post_thumbnail( array(140,180) ); ?>` But it still doesn't display the right sizes, is there a way to achive the exact sizes that I want?

Comment: i am not sure try this. this may helps you [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21739/wordpress-the-post-thumbnail-not-cropping-properly][1]


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21739/wordpress-the-post-thumbnail-not-cropping-properly

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a custom image size first and using a reference to that definition:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

In functions.php

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 ); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions   
}
```

Then you can use `<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnails' ); ?>`